# Ubuntu 15.04 Login loop

Tags: login, 15.04

So , yesterday I was playing some cs go with the open source graphics, but my fps were too damn low , with a ati 270x (approximately 40-50 with breaks), so I decided to install the fgrlx drivers to see if the gains in fps were significantly high. The install process went well , so I decided to restart, and then it happened : I got the login loop problem... And to get things worst, when I press ctrl +alt+f1, a black screens appears and not the terminal, and I can't really do the command sudo apt-get install linux-generic , that seems to be the solution within all the threads referring to the login loop bug . I'm running Ubuntu on a dual boot system with Windows 8.1 and dual monitor system.
If all the solutions fail , can someone link me a guide or a quick ELI5 how to reinstall ubuntu on a dual boot machine ?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks,

NEWS/EDIT: after going to recovery mode and unnistaling xserver-xorg and fglrx ,Ubuntu is finally running with updated kernel and Open source graphics,  Dual monitors also works fine now. No errors no nothing , all back to normal . Solution was to completely remove all drivers(open and proprietary)  and install them again.

Comment: [Edit] your question and tell us what happens when you press ctrl+alt+F6.

Comment: Tried them all , neither Ctrl-Alt-F1 F2 or F3....F6 work, just a black screen appears , and im forced to manually reboot or get back by pressing Ctrl-Alt-F7.
I have officialy run out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove these drivers by

1. booting into [recovery mode](//wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode#Booting_into_recovery_mode) and
2. running

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
   ```

Comment: The only problem is that , i cant access the terminal ....

Comment: So is login problem solved? Then ask another question regarding multimonitor.

Comment: See the Edit section pls

Comment: Please do not post in answers, post in your question.

Answer (score 0):

So i did it i guess but i have a little problem .
Going into recovery mode in the GRUB , and root prompt shell doing `apt-get purge fglrx -y`  alow me to enter again and no more login loop. But i have a dual monitor system , and now the system only detetecs one , and reproduces the same image to the both .

Edit: so my drivers where bad unnistalled , and after doing `sudo apt-get install purge fglrx*´  i now cant login to ubuntu at all , just a screen with the original color of ubuntu appears. Damn.

Comment: Sry about that , fixed now . Thanks for the help .  Edit in main post.